# Correct conjunction of two if/then statements

Tags: calculus, logic

Is the correct conjunction of the statements:

- if $x\geq0$ then $x\leq a$;
- if $x\leq0$ then $-a\leq x$

The conjunction:

if $x\leq0\leq x$ then $-a\leq x\leq a$ i.e. if $x=0$ then $-a\leq x\leq a$?

Comment: Try a function such as $a=f(x)=3x$ and see what you can make of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Note that the statement after i.e. only says what happens when $x=0$ while your first two tell you what happens for all values of $x$.  That should tell you it is not a correct conjunction.  The simple conjunction is just to string them together with and

> (If $x \ge 0$ then $x \le a$) and (If $x \le 0$ then $-a \le x)$

You might notice that this means that $|x| \le a$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp:  Right you are.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [if $x\geq0$ then $x\leq a$] can be written as [$x<0$ or $x\leq a$]. Analogously, the second statement can be written as [$x>0$ or $x\geq -a$]. Now, the conjunction is
$$[(x<0)\mbox{ or }(x\leq a)]\mbox{ and }[(x>0)\mbox{ or }(x\geq-a)].$$
This is equivalent to
$$[(x<0)\mbox{ and }(x>0)]\mbox{ or }[(x<0)\mbox{ and }(x\geq-a)]\mbox{ or }[(x\leq a)\mbox{ and }(x>0)]\mbox{ or }[(x\leq a)\mbox{ and }(x\geq-a)].$$
This is equivalent to
$$(-a\leq x<0)\mbox{ or }(0<x\leq a)\mbox{ or }(-a\leq x\leq a).$$
This can be written more easily as
$$a\geq0\mbox{ and }\|x\|\leq a.$$

Comment: We actually have $|b|\leq a$ iff $-a\leq b \leq a$. Is there a way to prove it using logic?